# Deeplearning4j - 1.0.0-M1.1 with Cuda - cudaGetSymbolAddress(...) failed error

Tags: java, deeplearning4j

I am getting the error as per showed in title. I have searched in Stackoverflow and  other people have been through by the same problem in previous versions.  In an answer was said that would be solved in a next version of DL4J and  it seems that it have not occurred.
Below are pom.xml and the dependencies i am using.
Please, can anybody help me?
Thank you in advance.

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <dl4j-master.version>1.0.0-M1.1</dl4j-master.version>

    <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven-shade-plugin.version>2.4.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-nlp</artifactId>
        <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datavec</groupId>
        <artifactId>datavec-api</artifactId>
        <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>nd4j-cuda-11.0-platform</artifactId>
        <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>cuda-platform-redist</artifactId>
        <version>11.0-8.0-1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>deeplearning4j-cuda-11.0</artifactId>
        <version>${dl4j-master.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>cuda</artifactId>
        <version>10.0-7.4-1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Error:

11:11:35.720 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4jBackend - Loaded [JCublasBackend] backend
11:11:37.543 [main] INFO org.nd4j.nativeblas.NativeOpsHolder - Number of threads used for linear algebra: 32
11:11:37.675 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.api.ops.executioner.DefaultOpExecutioner - Backend used: [CUDA]; OS: [Windows 10]
11:11:37.676 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.api.ops.executioner.DefaultOpExecutioner - Cores: [4]; Memory: [3,5GB];
11:11:37.676 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.api.ops.executioner.DefaultOpExecutioner - Blas vendor: [CUBLAS]
11:11:37.702 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.jcublas.JCublasBackend - ND4J CUDA build version: 11.0.221
11:11:37.705 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.jcublas.JCublasBackend - CUDA device 0: [NVIDIA GeForce 930M]; cc: [5.0]; Total memory: [4294836224]
11:11:37.705 [main] INFO org.nd4j.linalg.jcublas.JCublasBackend - Backend build information:
MSVC: 192930038
STD version: 201703L
CUDA: 11.0.221
DEFAULT_ENGINE: samediff::ENGINE_CUDA
HAVE_FLATBUFFERS
11:11:37.782 [main] INFO org.deeplearning4j.models.sequencevectors.SequenceVectors - Starting vocabulary building...
11:11:37.783 [main] DEBUG org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.wordstore.VocabConstructor - Target vocab size before building: [0]
11:11:37.814 [main] DEBUG org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.wordstore.VocabConstructor - Trying source iterator: [0]
11:11:37.814 [main] DEBUG org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.wordstore.VocabConstructor - Target vocab size before building: [0]
11:11:51.450 [main] DEBUG org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.wordstore.VocabConstructor - Waiting till all processes stop...
11:11:51.457 [main] DEBUG org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.wordstore.VocabConstructor - Vocab size before truncation: [168165],  NumWords: [1952392], sequences parsed: [318], counter: [1952389]
11:11:51.457 [main] DEBUG org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.wordstore.VocabConstructor - Vocab size after truncation: [168165],  NumWords: [1952392], sequences parsed: [318], counter: [1952389]
11:11:54.179 [main] INFO org.deeplearning4j.models.word2vec.wordstore.VocabConstructor - Sequences checked: [318], Current vocabulary size: [168165]; Sequences/sec: [19,39];
11:11:54.248 [main] INFO org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer - Projected memory use for model: [128,30 MB]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: cudaGetSymbolAddress(...) failed; Error code: [13]
at org.nd4j.linalg.jcublas.ops.executioner.CudaExecutioner.createShapeInfo(CudaExecutioner.java:2173)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.shape.Shape.createShapeInformation(Shape.java:3279)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseShapeInfoProvider.createShapeInformation(BaseShapeInfoProvider.java:75)
at org.nd4j.jita.constant.ProtectedCudaShapeInfoProvider.createShapeInformation(ProtectedCudaShapeInfoProvider.java:96)
at org.nd4j.jita.constant.ProtectedCudaShapeInfoProvider.createShapeInformation(ProtectedCudaShapeInfoProvider.java:77)
at org.nd4j.linalg.jcublas.CachedShapeInfoProvider.createShapeInformation(CachedShapeInfoProvider.java:46)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.(BaseNDArray.java:180)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.(BaseNDArray.java:174)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.(BaseNDArray.java:316)
at org.nd4j.linalg.jcublas.JCublasNDArray.(JCublasNDArray.java:135)
at org.nd4j.linalg.jcublas.JCublasNDArrayFactory.createUninitialized(JCublasNDArrayFactory.java:1533)
at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.createUninitialized(Nd4j.java:4379)
at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.rand(Nd4j.java:2957)
at org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j.rand(Nd4j.java:2946)
at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.inmemory.InMemoryLookupTable.resetWeights(InMemoryLookupTable.java:145)
at org.deeplearning4j.models.sequencevectors.SequenceVectors.fit(SequenceVectors.java:278)
at org.deeplearning4j.models.paragraphvectors.ParagraphVectors.fit(ParagraphVectors.java:667)
at gov.rfb.cocaj.dl4jGPU.DocumentClassifier.main(DocumentClassifier.java:44)

Answer (score 0):

This is always due to an incompatible cuda version. Make sure that the version you have installed locally is not different from the one you are using with dl4j.

Comment: thanks for your attention but, unless I'm mistaken, I'm using version 11.0 both pom.xml and in the program installed locally:
C:\Users\Ney>nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Thu_Jun_11_22:26:48_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.0, V11.0.194
Build cuda_11.0_bu.relgpu_drvr445TC445_37.28540450_0